# Working with creating wordpress post types

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating my custom post type and all is working well however I just have a simple question concerning how I make it show up.

I've creative my custom post type in my fuctions.php file and made a single-speakers.php file. How do I direct my custom post type speakers page to my "SAFETY SPEAKERS" tab in the main navigation?

[THIS IS MY SITE](http://www.safetyspeakers.ca)

[This is the actual link to my custom post type page with my speakers on it](http://safetyspeakers.ca/?speakers=linda-edgecombe)

fuctions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_post_types' );

function create_my_post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'speakers',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Speakers' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Speakers' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

single-speakers.php

```
<?php get_template_part( 'header', '2' );      // Header #2 (header-2.php) ?>

<?php query_posts( 'post_type=speakers'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div id="speakersBox" class="clearfix"><?php the_title('<h6>', '</h6>'); ?><br/><?php the_content(); ?></div>
            <hr>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


<?php get_template_part( 'footer', '2' );      // Footer #2 (footer-2.php) ?>
```

Any help and or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `single-speakers.php` template to display Single Speaker Post type. Add `template_redirect` action by checking post. Put this in your `functions.php` file. i.e.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_speaker');
function redirect_to_speaker(){
   global $post;
   if(is_single() && $post->post_type == 'speakers'){
       include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-speakers.php');
       exit;
   }
}
```

Alternatively. You can use a filter called `template_include`. In fact use this one:

```
 add_filter('template_include', 'my_speaker_template');
 function my_speaker_template($template){
       global $post;
       if(is_single() && $post->post_type == 'speakers'){
           $template = get_template_directory() . '/single-speakers.php';
       }
       return $template;
 }
```

Also, read this article with some very good information about Templates: http://xazure.net/2011/06/tips-snippets/wordpress/changing-wordpress-template-with-template_include/

Comment: I added in the code I have for my single-speakers.php file into my question. I tried your code but it's not closed properly? It's saying there is a closing error, do I need to put it in a specific spot? (it's above the my create custom post type action in the functions.php file).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that put this code in your `functions.php` file. And I have edited the code. Try now.

Comment: I added it, however I'm not quite understanding what it's supposed to do. Could you shed some light on this for me?

Comment: `template_redirect` is basically a hook that we can use to replace the default template with another template. Alternatively you can also use another hook named `template_include` to load a different template. Let me update the code for you.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. How is this going to link the custom post types I've entered to my "Safety Speakers" page?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well I figured out a way. I created a new template page with the info from the single-speakers.php file (and called it page-speakers.php) and pointed my Safety Speakers page to that new page. It works great!

Thanks for your help Naveed, I appreciate it anyways.